# Login to website with no api exposed

Tags: android, authentication

I'm trying to write my first app where in I login to website and setup some preferences. 
My problem is this website does not have api's or documentation on how to do it. This is my first time doing any kind of web programming. Please pardon me if my questions are naive.

While reading android documentation and searching through Stack overflow i understand HTTPPOST is the preferable way to do such a thing.

1. If the website does not provide URI and documentation, how to figure out these things? I tried looking at the HTML source code. I could figure out login form. I'm not sure if that always works.
2. How to figure out which encoding is to be used while creating HTTPPOST requests?
3. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think u must parse html . try see this mb it's help u  [Android : Parse HTML block of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020466/android-parse-html-block-of-code)